# I'm trying to generate a list of random numbers in a string that's based on user input in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a simple dice rolling program for DnD, and I'm trying to make it so that you can roll any amount of dice and it shows you a list of the rolls. I'm still a little rusty at python, and I'm running into difficulty. Here's what I have (note: this is for a 4 sided dice):

```
List = []

def Dice():
     List = List + [random.randint(1, 4)]
     return List

while multiplier > 0:
     Dice()
     multiplier = multiplier - 1   #multiplier is how many times you rolled the dice
print(Dice())
```

Whenever it runs, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Un-Local User/Desktop/Python/Dice Sim.py", line 68, in <module>
      Dice()
   File "C:/Users/Un-Local User/Desktop/Python/Dice Sim.py", line 5, in Dice
      List = List + [random.randint(1, 4)]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'List' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Your function Dice doesn't know what is the value of "List". declare "global List" within your function. BTW don't use system reserved word "List", try using different variable names

Comment: @VijayLingam Actually `List` is not builtin function, it is `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the variable `List` global to use or modify them in function:

```
import random
global List
List = []

def Dice():
    global List
    List = List + [random.randint(1, 4)]
    return List

while multiplier > 0:
    Dice()
    multiplier = multiplier - 1   #multiplier is how many times you rolled the dice
print(Dice())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` Read [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append)

For the unbound error, here's a good [explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

```
from random import randint

List = []
def Dice():
     List.append(randint(1, 4))
     return List

multiplier = 4
while multiplier > 0:
     Dice()
     multiplier = multiplier - 1   #multiplier is how many times you rolled the dice

print(Dice())
```

Comment: I don't know why in your code `List.append(randint(1, 4))` is fine but in the OP's code `List = List + [random.randint(1, 4)]` led to error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'List' referenced before assignment"? I thought he needs `global List` but I don't see why yours doesn't!

Comment: I edit my answer to reference the UnbondLocalError explanation